# Non useable icons appearing in the unity dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, duplicate

I have no idea what the heck is going on with the unity dash. However, or every application I have installed and is visible on the unity dash, their is a blank icon for it that shows the generic package icon. Or an application like K3B, will not only have the functional icon, but it also shows the older icon as well.

The new and old icons appear for Evolution, and generic icons are "Peppered" all over the place

[image]

Comment: Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

Those application icons (together with general applications info) are stored in .desktop files in this directory:

```
~/.local/share/applications
```

All you need to do is go to that directory and remove *.desktop file(s) manually. eg:

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications
rm program1.desktop program2.desktop program3.desktop
```

and so on.